# historically why people believe 5 and higher polynomials dont have general radical solution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

So it is known back to the 19th century Abel proved, five and higher degrees polynomials don't have a general radical solution. I wonder in what reasons people started to believe instead of finding the general radical solutions, we should prove the nonexistence. Did numerical solutions to the polynomial equations help? Or are there any refs about this history? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wikipedia at least has some history on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem